# Tensorflow ,AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

**I write this code**

```
from statistics import mode

import cv2

from keras.models import load_model

import numpy as np

import utils

from utils.datasets import get_labels

from utils.inference import detect_faces

from utils.inference import draw_text

from utils.inference import draw_bounding_box

from utils.inference import apply_offsets

from utils.inference import load_detection_model

from utils.preprocessor import preprocess_input
```

**but it doesn't work.**

**this is error message**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16116/1295457466.py in <module>
      2 
      3 import cv2
----> 4 from keras.models import load_model
      5 import numpy as np
      6 import utils


C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\version.py in <module>
     15 
     16 from collections import namedtuple
---> 17 from . import h5 as _h5
     18 import sys
     19 import numpy

h5py\h5.pyx in init h5py.h5()

**AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5.H5PYConfig' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'**
```

**I tried conda uninstall tensorflow,conda uninstall h5py
and reinstall but still have this error.
how can i fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall  h5py package a few times and then reinstall it again.

```
pip uninstall h5py
pip install h5py
```